# Pytest assertRaisesWithMessage(ValueError) failing even though ValueError raised

Tags: python, pytest

The pytest test suite is failing on two tests even though a value error is raised and I have placed a print to make sure that the conditional is being activated and it is, does anyone have any ideas the two tests are failing?

### Code

```
import string

class PhoneNumber:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = ''.join([el for el in number if el in string.digits])
        
        if len(self.number) <= 9 or len(self.number) > 11:
            raise ValueError('Number length is incorrect')
        elif len(self.number) == 11:
            if self.number.startswith('1'):
                self.number = self.number[1::]
                if self.number.startswith('0') or self.number.startswith('1'):
                    print('+++ This fires +++')
                    raise ValueError('Incorrect area code')
            else:
                raise ValueError('Number does not start with 1')
        elif self.number[0] == '0' or self.number[0] == '1':
            raise ValueError('Incorrect area code') 
        elif self.number[3] == '0' or self.number[3] == '1':
            raise ValueError('Incorrect exchange code')

    def area_code(self):
        return self.number[:3]
    
    def pretty(self):
        return '('+ self.number[:3] +') ' + self.number[3:6] + '-' + self.number[6::]

PhoneNumber("1 (023) 456-7890")
```

### Tests

```
def test_invalid_if_area_code_starts_with_0_on_valid_11_digit_number(self):
        with self.assertRaisesWithMessage(ValueError):
            PhoneNumber("1 (023) 456-7890")

def test_invalid_if_area_code_starts_with_1_on_valid_11_digit_number(self):
        with self.assertRaisesWithMessage(ValueError):
            PhoneNumber("1 (123) 456-7890")
```

### Output when running the code outside the test suite

```
+++ This fires +++
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Exercism/python/phone-number/phone_number.py", line 28, in <module>
    PhoneNumber("1 (023) 456-7890")
  File "Exercism/python/phone-number/phone_number.py", line 14, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Incorrect area code')
ValueError: Incorrect area code
```

### Pytest output

```
=========================================================================== FAILURES =========================================================================== 
_____________________________________ PhoneNumberTest.test_invalid_if_exchange_code_starts_with_0_on_valid_11_digit_number _____________________________________ 

self = <phone_number_test.PhoneNumberTest testMethod=test_invalid_if_exchange_code_starts_with_0_on_valid_11_digit_number>

    def test_invalid_if_exchange_code_starts_with_0_on_valid_11_digit_number(self):
        with self.assertRaisesWithMessage(ValueError):
>           PhoneNumber("1 (223) 056-7890")
E           AssertionError: ValueError not raised

phone_number_test.py:75: AssertionError
_____________________________________ PhoneNumberTest.test_invalid_if_exchange_code_starts_with_1_on_valid_11_digit_number _____________________________________ 

self = <phone_number_test.PhoneNumberTest testMethod=test_invalid_if_exchange_code_starts_with_1_on_valid_11_digit_number>

    def test_invalid_if_exchange_code_starts_with_1_on_valid_11_digit_number(self):
        with self.assertRaisesWithMessage(ValueError):
>           PhoneNumber("1 (223) 156-7890")
E           AssertionError: ValueError not raised

phone_number_test.py:79: AssertionError
=================================================================== short test summary info ==================================================================== 
FAILED phone_number_test.py::PhoneNumberTest::test_invalid_if_exchange_code_starts_with_0_on_valid_11_digit_number - AssertionError: ValueError not raised       
FAILED phone_number_test.py::PhoneNumberTest::test_invalid_if_exchange_code_starts_with_1_on_valid_11_digit_number - AssertionError: ValueError not raised       
================================================================= 2 failed, 19 passed in 0.78s =================================================================
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `assertRaisesWithMessage`, which is not a default method in `unittest.TestCase`, but I assume that it expects a message, which defaults to an empty string. As you don't provide a message, the check fails.

If you want to use standard `unittest` methods, you can either use:

```py
def test_invalid_if_area_code_starts_with_0_on_valid_11_digit_number(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        PhoneNumber("1 (023) 456-7890")
```

or, if you *want* to test the message:

```py
def test_invalid_if_area_code_starts_with_0_on_valid_11_digit_number(self):
    with self.assertRaisesRegex(ValueError, "Incorrect area code"):
        PhoneNumber("1 (023) 456-7890")
```

That being said, it looks like you are mixing `unittest` and `pytest`. While this is possible, I would advice against it, except for old `unittest` code.

Using `pytest`, the test would look like this:

```py
def test_invalid_if_area_code_starts_with_0_on_valid_11_digit_number(self):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        PhoneNumber("1 (023) 456-7890")
```

or

```py
def test_invalid_if_area_code_starts_with_0_on_valid_11_digit_number(self):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="Incorrect area code"):
        PhoneNumber("1 (023) 456-7890")
```

Comment: You should use the suggestion `with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="Incorrect area code"):`. This is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the last line from `phone_number.py`, where you instantiate an invalid `PhoneNumber`. This is causing an error to happen before your tests even run. I assume you left that line in as a typo?

For clarity, it is this line:

```
PhoneNumber("1 (023) 456-7890")
```

You are testing that this line is invalid but it is always run in your `phone_number.py` module.

Comment: Hi, I left that line in to demonstrate my manual testing of the code. That line is not inplace when I run pytest.

Comment: The problem is probably with how you are using this custom function `assertRaisesWithMessage`. Can you update your question to show us what this function looks like?

Comment: Hi the test suite was provided with the exercise from exercism.io. I don't want to post the full test file as it is over 100 lines. It does import unittest so I assumue that is what they are basing the tests off of but I can't understand why the error is not being logged if it rasied when I 'simulate' the test manually.

Comment: You don't have to post the full test file. Just that single function.
Basically, if I had to guess, I would guess that function needs the expected message as an argument, and should be called like this: `with self.assertRaisesWithMessage(ValueError, message="Invalid area code"):`

Comment: assertRaisesWithMessage isn't defined anywhere, However, I do have other tests within the test file which uses the same assertRaisesWithMessage function and they pass when I run the file, just the two in the main post that fails for some reason.

Comment: If you are just learning python then the best thing you could do is forget about this `assertRaisesWithMessage` thing because it doesn't exist anywhere outside of exercism.io. Instead you should learn `with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="Incorrect area code")` because this is extremely common and useful.

Comment: Okay thank you for your advice. I have been refactoring my code endlessly trying to get those two test cases to pass.

Comment: No worries, fellow coder :) Good luck with your learning.